# Identify old road bicycle frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Does anybody have idea what is this bicycle frame? We are considering with a friend restoring it and would be grateful for any info, also is it worth it.

Frame is totally without any stickers or manufacturer marks, only spray on it. Only thing characteristic are stars visible on the two connections and under bottom and probably Campagnolo hooks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE3E4.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I would call it a better than average bike from ca 1980.  The stars are the best identifying marks, though that does look like "CAMPAGNOLO" stamped on the dropout.  Nice bike!

Answer (score 3):

The star cutouts in the lugs and BB identify it as a [Guerciotti](http://www.guerciotti.it/en/). I couldn't find vintage Guerciotti star pictures on their site, but there are other photos easily available via a Google [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=guerciotti+star+cutout).